# Any compact subset containing Z implies Z is compact

Tags: general-topology

Theorem:

Let X be a topological space, let Y be a compact subspace of X and let Z be a subset of Y that is closed with respect to Z. Then Z is compact also.

I have an intuition that there is a mistake in the theorem above. It should be "Z is closed with respect to X"
This is from my notes and it has been known to be riddled with mistakes.

Can anyone clarify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah,  everything is closed in respect to itself, so that's no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course "$Z$ is closed respect to $Z$" is not going to help anything! Must be a typo. Either "$Z$ closed with respect to $X$" or "$Z$ closed with respect to $Y$" would work.